# How to handle a completion handler that never gets called by API?

Tags: swift, completionhandler

```
APIClient?.update(Record, completion: { response, error in
                dLog(response)
                dLog(error)
           })
```

We've been trying to work through a buggy API that is provided by another company. Sometimes, the API works and I get a response record. Occasionally, the update disappears into a blackhole and completion never gets called, so I don't get an error either.

Ultimately we want the API to be fixed, but what is the correct way to catch this in the meantime so I can popup an alert?

I've used XCTest/expectation/waitFor, but I think that's mainly for Unit Testing, not sure if that could apply here.

Comment: If it truly never returns, then a timer seems like a possibility.  Assuming the API has no timeout settings you can use, then you'd need to decide what a good proxy value is for "never" and show your alert then.

Comment: And that in fact is how a timeout works with unit tests; it's just a timer.